# When are camera files saved in Android when I take pictures this way?

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

So I tried to follow using code from http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html but apparently had some infamous "null Intent" error, so I am trying to understand how everything works. I have several questions so I'll split each one up into its own SO question. I'll start with thumbnails.

If I take a picture this way:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Then I get a thumbnail / Bitmap of the picture I took. Is the picture I took still in my filesystem somewhere in full form, or did my camera basically take a full picture (which I can see in the camera app itself, when I can click either Retry/OK after taking the picture), throw it away, and give me a Bitmap of the thumbnail, or did it save the full file in some weird default location and only return me the thumbnail?

Comment: When you take a picture, the bitmap data first remains in memory of your device (RAM), not your file system. Then when you decide to save your data to the file system, you can save this bitmap data to the file system by using File class and FileOutputStream.

Comment: So when I have not specified a filename, the picture is saved in RAM (which is temporary storage, not permanent, gets cleared, etc), and the Bitmap thumbnail is passed into the Intent? Is this thumbnail also in RAM?

Comment: Yes, in Intent in onActivityResult() you get data straight from RAM. You can save it to your file or do nothing. If you'll do nothing, garbage collector will clean it up later and your picture will be lost.

Comment: So then is the difference, that if I _do_ pass in a filename such as using `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));` then nothing is saved in the Intent necessarily? (edit: Or maybe, to clarify, it is considered safer to work with the filepath directly since you know that there will be a file there -- there may or may not be something in the Intent depending on camera implementation?)

Comment: Well, photoFile in this case is only a path to your still empty file. You created a file, but there's nothing yet. You take a picture, accept it, you go back to the previous Activity and onActivityResult() gets called. Now you have the access to the Bitmap data and you can save this data to your previously created empty file. If you know what I mean.

Comment: But the problem I had before was that when I used the code I posted in the OP, I'd get the thumbnail fine (but I don't know where the full file is now). If I used `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));` then suddenly the intent was null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108188/discussion-between-jerry-and-sean-hill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is up to the camera app implementation.

There are thousands of Android device models, shipping with hundreds of pre-installed camera apps. There are also many other camera apps available for download via the Play Store and elsewhere. Those apps merely have to abide by the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` contract (and some fail to even do that). *How* those camera apps fulfil that contract is up to those apps' developers.

Comment: I am at a loss for how I am supposed to implement any sort of camera activity into my app because "everything is different" does not help me much. The code from Android's own site does not seem to offer much light on the topic. How can I _tell_ what my camera is doing? How do I know how I have to change the implementation? What is the "`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` contract"?

Comment: @SeanHill: "I am at a loss for how I am supposed to implement any sort of camera activity into my app" -- follow [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), and do not assume anything beyond those instructions. "How can I tell what my camera is doing?" -- you don't, in general. For example, the camera app could upload the photo to some Web server. You have no way of spying on that activity. You are delegating work to a third-party app; how that app does that work is none of your business, to be honest.

Comment: @SeanHill: If your lack of control concerns you, do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use the camera APIs, or [libraries built atop of those APIs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2), to take pictures in your own app, rather than delegating to some other app. "What is the "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE contract"?" -- that is [the aforementioned documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

Comment: So what do most people do? Just assume people abide by the contract? Because then otherwise you'd have to make several if-statements checking all possible ways a camera implementation might work, no?

Comment: @SeanHill: "Because then otherwise you'd have to make several if-statements checking all possible ways a camera implementation might work, no?" -- correct. However, production-grade code needs to validate inputs and gracefully degrade. The biggest sanity check is if you provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, to confirm that there really is a file there in `onActivityResult()`. Some camera apps have bugs where they don't save the file in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, even though you asked them to.

Comment: When I send `EXTRA_OUTPUT` as an argument (using `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));`), the Intent I get back is null.

Comment: @SeanHill: Sure. You're not supposed to get anything back in that case. Just look in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to see if your image is there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` just contains a string called `output` (I added a watch to this)

Comment: @SeanHill: By "look in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`", I mean "look in the location specified by the `Uri` that you placed in the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`". In your case, this apparently is the file pointed to by `photoFile`, though note that [`Uri.fromFile()` will not work on the N Developer Preview 1 if your `targetSdkVersion` is `N`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Comment: @SeanHill: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) demonstrating the use of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Note that it suffers from the aforementioned Android N problem, which I will need to fix.

Comment: Do I have to make photofile a member variable so I can access it from the onActivityResult?

Comment: @SeanHill: "Do I have to make photofile a member variable so I can access it from the onActivityResult?" -- not only that, but you need to hold onto it across configuration changes/process termination, by putting it in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. This is all horrifically confusing and it's honestly turning me off to Android development, which I was having so much fun with up until this point. This camera business is a mess and I don't understand why there isn't clearer documentation out there explaining how all this works and how you need to handle these cases. I'll accept this answer / give the checkmark but I honestly am even more lost than I was before.

Comment: @SeanHill: "I don't understand what that means" -- it has nothing specific to do with the camera. See [the documentation on configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for some background.

Comment: You're saying that if I were to rotate the screen to destroy/recreate the activity, it would also destroy any photofile references?

Comment: @SeanHill: It will not destroy the file. However, the new `Activity` is a fresh object, with fresh fields, and so a `photoFile` field will be `null`. This will also occur if your process is terminated while you are in the background, which is a normal Android event but catches some developers when dealing with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Hence, hold onto the value of `photoFile` via the saved instance state `Bundle`. This is demonstrated in [the sample app that I linked to previously](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content).

Comment: In general is it good practice to put all your member variables into the Bundle via `onSaveInstanceState` and then do the null-check/create-new-or-get-from-the-bundle approach for each of them in the onCreate method?

Comment: @SeanHill: Only the member variables that you need to and can. Many you won't, because they get derived from other things (e.g., a `MenuItem` that will get re-created in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`). Some you can't, because a `Bundle` cannot handle arbitrary data types (e.g., `Socket`). I mean, I have [a whole book chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/resource-sets-and-configurations) on dealing with configuration changes. It's not the sort of thing that can fit in a 500-character Stack Overflow comment. :-)

Comment: I'll make a new question on this topic.